# php Send validation email after registration

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, xampp

I am new to PHP, PHPMyAdmin, Localhost, etc.. I am currently bulding a website which I am testing on my localhost (I have installed Xampp on my Ubuntu). I wanted to make a registration form, which works fine (everything goes to my database), but I would like to see which users have in fact activated their account.

So I would like to make a validation mail with an unique code in it. The problem right now is that I tried to type in: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`, but I found out it doesn't work.

I tried to install sendmail, postfix, dovecot, telnet, etc. but nothing seems to work, and I couldn't find a good walkthrough.

I work with the following things: ubuntu (12.04LTS), xampp (php5.5), localhost/phpmyadmin.

If somebody knows a good walkthrough, or knows how to make this work, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: A tutorial to install postfix https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Comment: Try your send mail function by typing: "sendmail sample-email@example.org" in cmd-line. Then your message, send by pushing ctrl+D if evrything is setup alright that schould send a mail to sample-email@example.org

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief tutorial that may help.

http://sourcelibrary.org/2011/08/29/how-to-set-up-the-php-mail-function-on-a-ubuntu-linux-lamp-server/

Did you update your php.ini file with this line?

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

And then restart apache afterwards.

Comment: I already update my php.ini mail, I followed the tutorial but I didn't receive a mail

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHPMailer. It's a powerful library for sending e-mails in PHP.

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Here I'll put a single example for you.
First of all, **download** PHPMailer for your computer. 
Second, require the PHPMailerAutoload.php from the location when it is installed. In my example, it's in the directory phpmailer. This one (phpmailer) is in the same directory as my app, so:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

I took this example from PHPMailer Github's https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps

You can also use your GMail account (if you have one) to send e-mails
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

There are other examples there.

Let us know how you fixed it.
Good luck.